# Why can't we command two DC motors with just 2 relays for each in opposite directions with a same power supply?

Tags: dc-motor, h-bridge

We managed to control 2 DC motors with 2 relays for each one.It worked great except one thing:
we couldn't  make them turn in opposite directions at the same time .We noticed that there was a shot circuit.
Can somebody explain it please?
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Please add a schematic of your setup, and add some information about the relays you've been using.

Comment: You can control the direction of a motor with a single relay, but it must be a double pole one.

Comment: Google: 'h-bridge motor direction'

Comment: You obviously messed up the wiring, since if you can drive one motor with two relays, you should be able to drive any number of motors with two relays each (up to the capacity of the power supply, of course). ... Unless the motors have hidden (internal) connections between their power terminals and their cases, which could create a short through their mountings.

Comment: No one who posted comments or answers seems to have had much difficulty in either understanding the OP's query or asking for further information, so why are a few non-contributors to the thread putting the question on hold?

Comment: @EMFields: The question is "unclear" because the OP never came back and showed us exactly what he had done. Therefore, no specific answer can be given.

Comment: I am using 2 simple relays (sorry i don't have the reference right now) for each motor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it; where's the short?[image]